# In my Rails 4 app, I'm getting "undefined method `admin?'" even though I have defined a method in my user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, model

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  I’m getting the error “undefined method `admin?' for #<User:0x007f9b3a9bff78>” on the below code

```
user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
session[:user_id] = user.id
if user.admin?
  render 'admin/index'
else
  redirect_to root_path
```

However, I thought the below method I defined in my user model would take care of the above …

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, through: :assignments

  def role?(role)
    roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role }
  end
```

And in my database I have two roles defined …

```
mydb=> select * FROM roles;
 id | name  |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | Admin | 2016-04-28 19:55:43.473016 | 2016-04-28 19:55:43.473016
  2 | User  | 2016-04-28 19:55:43.492222 | 2016-04-28 19:55:43.492222
```

Any help is appreciated, -

Comment: in your model, you have not defined any method named as admin? Its a role you are passing to a method named role?

Comment: `if user.role? "admin"` - try this as you have defined `role?(role)` as a method in `User` model

Comment: there's no 'admin?' method defined in your model, and 'role?' will not take care of it automatically. Perhaps you could do, is to define the `method_missing` method and do the logic there, something like method_missing(name, *args, &block), and then in the method's body something like role?(name[0..2]) if name.to_s.end_with?('?')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined a method named `admin?` in your `User` model rather you have a `role?` method which takes `role` as an argument. So you call

```
if user.role? "admin"
```

instead of

```
if user.admin?
```

Or

Simply define a method in your model as:

```
def admin?
    role? "admin"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `app/models/user.rb`:

```
def admin?
  role? :admin
end
```